# HttpSession Servlet don't work correctly from a servlet to a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

Good afternoon, I'm trying to recover an instantiated object from a servlet in the HttpSession object.

When I try to recover from the JSP, I get the object smoothly.
However when I try to retrieve this data from another Servlet, not me gets the object, It returns me  NULL directly, although the session ID is the same.

Here's the code where I instantiate the object to pass:

```
request.getSession(true);
request.getSession().setAttribute("object1", object1);
```

This is the code that attempt to retrieve the object.

```
req.getSession().getAttribute("object1");
```

Can you think of anything?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: How do you call your second servlet ? Where do you call it from ?

Comment: may be cookie is disable for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In jspkeep the data in session like this way

`session.setAttribute("object1", object1);` and retrieve in servlet like this way

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
session.getAttribute("object1");
```

Comment: session.setAttribute() is different from request.getSession() in jsp

Comment: they are different i know but does it causing the issue here? `true` is just creating a new session if not present as it has been created so it should not create the issue.

Comment: @Trying Then we have to wait till OP leaves a comment whether my answer works or not

Comment: i am removing my down vote but i am sure it is not contributing to the issue.

Comment: @Trying if it does not work then i will better delete my answer but I am sure cookies are not disabled otherwise getting in jsp is also not possible

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Listing 3: Storing an Object

public class logonServlet extends HttpServlet{

public void service(HttpServletRequest _req, HttpServletRe-

sponse _res) throws ServletException{

ServletContext thisContext = getServletContext();

//-- Assume some method creates a new connection class

Connection newConnection = createConnection();

thisContext.setAttribute( "database.connection", newConnection );

//-- Return some output to the client

} 
}

Listing 4: retrieving an Object

public class logoffServlet extends HttpServlet{

public void service(HttpServletRequest _req, HttpServletRe- 
sponse _res) throws ServletException{

ServletContext thisContext = getServletContext();

//-- Assume some method creates a new connection class

Connection newConnection = thisContext.getAttribute( 
"database.connection");

if ( newConnection == null )

//- Database has not been opened yet

//-- Return some output to the client

} 
}

Source: http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0505/williamson2/index.html